# XDocument.Validate returning The Element has invalid child element

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xml-validation

Getting a really strange issue today while trying to validate XML using XSD.
Looking at the XML I'm providing, it looks correct.

The error I'm receiving from XDocument.Validate is:
The element '**APPOINTMENTS**' had invalid child element '**APPOINTMENT**'

Here is the XML I'm using:

```
<PATIENTS>
    <PATIENT>
        <APPOINTMENTS>
            <APPOINTMENT>
                <UserInitials>123</UserInitials>
                <Date>Some Date</Date>
                <ApptTime>14:30</ApptTime>
                <Duration>00:15</Duration>
                <AppointmentStatus>Complete</AppointmentStatus>
                <Notes>Some note</Notes>
                <TreatmentType>Some Appoinment type</TreatmentType>
            </APPOINTMENT>
        </APPOINTMENTS>
    </PATIENT>
</PATIENTS>
```

And the XSD file I'm validating against:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
 <xs:element name="PATIENTS">
   <xs:complexType>
     <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="PATIENT" minOccurs="1">
         <xs:complexType>
           <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element name="APPOINTMENTS" minOccurs="0">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="APPOINTMENT" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:complexType>
                      <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="UserInitials" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"></xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="Date" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"></xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="ApptTime" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"></xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="Duration" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"></xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="AppointmentStatus" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"></xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="LegacyTypeID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="AClinic" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="Notes" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="Info" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="TreatmentType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" default="Examination"></xs:element>
                      </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                  </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
             </xs:element>
           </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>
       </xs:element>
     </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I don't quite understand what is happening, it looks like the Appointments and Appointments tags are conforming to the XSD file.

The rest of the XML document looks correct, unless there is an issue with the XSD file.

I do have other Elements within my Patient Element that are working fine.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with a .NET 4.5 C# console application doing `            XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
            schemaSet.Add(null, "../../XMLSchema1.xsd");
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("../../XMLFile1.xml");
            doc.Validate(schemaSet, (o, valArgs) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", valArgs.Severity, valArgs.Message);
            });` and your provided files.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Martin, I've also tried what you did, it must be something before the Appointment/Appointments element causing the problem, as it worked when I just used those files.

Comment: Can you provide any samples allowing us to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I've worked it out now, and added the answer below. but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked out the problem, I was actually missing part of the XML to show you.

I should have included the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<PATIENTS>
  <PATIENT>
    <APPOINTMENTS>
      <APPOINTMENT>
        <UserInitials>123</UserInitials>
        <Date>Some Date</Date>
        <ApptTime>14:30</ApptTime>
        <Duration>00:15</Duration>
        <AppointmentStatus>Complete</AppointmentStatus>
        <Notes>Some note</Notes>
        <TreatmentType>Some Appoinment type</TreatmentType>
      </APPOINTMENT>
      <APPOINTMENT>
        <UserInitials>123</UserInitials>
        <Date>Some Date</Date>
        <ApptTime>14:30</ApptTime>
        <Duration>00:15</Duration>
        <AppointmentStatus>Complete</AppointmentStatus>
        <Notes>Some note</Notes>
        <TreatmentType>Some Appoinment type</TreatmentType>
      </APPOINTMENT>
      <APPOINTMENT>
        <UserInitials>123</UserInitials>
        <Date>Some Date</Date>
        <ApptTime>14:30</ApptTime>
        <Duration>00:15</Duration>
        <AppointmentStatus>Complete</AppointmentStatus>
        <Notes>Some note</Notes>
        <TreatmentType>Some Appoinment type</TreatmentType>
      </APPOINTMENT>
    </APPOINTMENTS>
  </PATIENT>
</PATIENTS>
```

I Actually have multiple records within the APPOINTMENT Element, which would require the XSD file to have the following on the APPOINTMENT element:

```
<xs:element name="APPOINTMENT" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
```

I was missing the `maxOccurs="unbounded"` attribute